# How to use Mobicents sipservlets ws transport when acting as a UAC?

Tags: tomcat, webrtc, mobicents-sip-servlets

I need a bit of assistance in mobicents sipservlets
and defining ws or wss transports when acting as a client looking at the

https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/blob/master/sip-servlets-examples/websocket-b2bua/src/main/java/org/mobicents/servlet/sip/example/WebSocketB2BUASipServlet.java
example and it looks to depend on the aor carrying a ws contact to define the destination transport. Looking at the JSR 289 spec only udp", "tcp", "sctp", "tls" are defined and others can be defined as well. Would the container be prepared to be sent wss or wss when using 
SipURI.setTransportParam

?

Any guidance would appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Support for ws and wss transports were added. You can use them safely.

Comment: Thanks Jean,
Can you tell me what version supports wss as a client? I've attempted using mss-3.0.564-apache-tomcat-7.0.50 and found that I can send a request via ws but not wss. In addition the latest version using tomcat is missing interface definitions in server.xml for the wss transport although it does carry them for ws.

Comment: You should use the latest version https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets/releases/tag/v3.1.633 or the one from cloudbees that's not released yet https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestcommSipServlets-Release